# Assistance needed Understanding Android fragment addition during onCreate

Tags: android, android-fragments

I just need help cleaning up some information that doesn't make sense to me, with use cases if possible.

WHAT I UNDERSTAND:

With fragments in android, I understand that if you plan on replacing them you need to have a container view, preferably a FrameLayout, and add the initial fragment to the container during the activities onCreate method.  But there is one thing that continues to not make sense to me.

WHAT I DON'T UNDERSTAND AND NEED HELP WITH:

What rules are there regarding where/how the container view is set up, if there are any.  Android Developers site makes it look like the container view needs to be it's own XML layout file, but it doesn't say that and I have seen examples on here with FrameLayouts nested inside of your typical layout files, but they are all specific uses and I need to understand the rules of setting a container up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no rules. You just need any `ViewGroup` -- position and size it however you want. When you add the `Fragment` into it, it will behave just as if you'd created the `Fragment`'s `View` manually, and called `yourViewGroup.addView(fragmentView)`.

`FrameLayout` is typically used just because it makes a good container with no real behavior (you just give it a size and position and let the fragment fill that container).

There's absolutely no need to make the container view its own layout file. In fact, if you want the `Fragment` to take over the content view of the entire `Activity`, you could even just add the `Fragment` to the `Activity` using the ID `android.R.id.content`.

Comment: so in the event of placing a FrameLayout at the base of a RelativeLayout XML file, and then assigning a fragment to that layout in the activities onCreate method AFTER setContentView has been called to the XML file, that would work just as well as adding it to a dedicated FrameLayout XML file? Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: Correct. It just adds the Fragment's view to your view hierarchy, so whether that FrameLayout is included from a separate file, or directly written into your primary layout, it still ends up in the same place (assuming I'm understanding you correctly). Just think of it like placing any other View in your layout -- the container is just the container for the view (the fragment) that will be inserted at runtime.

Comment: got it thank you, there was so little info and so many code implementations that didn't seem to be working that I got uber confused. Your a life saver =)